# Relationship between expectation and probability

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$.

If $P(X < Y)\leq \varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon > 0$ does it follow that $\mathbb{E}[X] < \mathbb{E}[Y]$ where we put $\varepsilon$ in an appropriate way?

Or can we have $P(X < Y) \leq \varepsilon $ and $\mathbb{E}[X] > \mathbb{E}[Y]$ with an appropriate $\varepsilon$. I would appreciate if you could give me a counterexample.

Comment: What does "if $P(X<Y)$ " mean?  Did you mean something like "if $P(X<Y)=1$"?

Comment: @lulu: Thanks a lot for catching up the typo. Now I edited the question

Comment: In that case, the answer is "it depends what you mean by 'appropriate'".  Consider, say, $Y=1$ identically, and $X=0$ with probability $1-\epsilon$ and $X=\frac {10^{100}}{\epsilon}$ with probability $\epsilon$.

Comment: thanks for the example. I am curious if there is any theorem which relates those two quantities together

Comment: If $P(X\lt Y)\le \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon \gt 0$, then $P(X\ge Y)=1$ so $E(X)\ge E(Y)$.  If $\epsilon\gt 0$ is fixed, then anything is possible.